# How to configure Per App VPN in iOS7?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7, vpn

Is anybody know how to configure Per App VPN for iOS7? What are steps to follow for the implementation? What are steps to test the application after the implementation. 
Let me know if any guidance link available. There is very few information available on the web.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by the following way..
Please refer to the link below:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99988/how-to-configure-vpn-per-app-in-ios-7

Comment: I am getting error while configuring Safari Domains as "MKBDeviceLockAssertion: MKBDeviceLockAssertion (asserttype:3)
my-iPad profiled[2634] <Notice>: (Error) MC: Could not add Safari App VPN rules"

Please help!!